# Reduce dropdown width in select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

The dropdown list takes the width of the longest value, which in my case is pretty long. I want to reduce the width of the dropdown list to the width of the select box itself (70% in my case). Have tried a no. of options in various other StackOverflow questions, but I haven't been able to solve this.

Select box code:

```
<select id="college" name="college" placeholder="College Name">
          <option name="">{{ user.college.name }}</option>

          {% for college in colleges %}
          <option class="colleges" value="{{ college.url }}" name="college">{{ college.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could use Select2. It makes them look way nicer and will solve your problem as well.

Comment: Something [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/6s21LL47/)

Comment: @lshetty Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a few things:

1. set a fixed `width` to your `select`
2. use `title` in your `option`
3. use 3rd apps

#### set a fixed `width` to your `select`

```css
select {
    width:75px; /*whatever you want*/
}
```

```html
<select name="college" id="college">
    <option value="small">small</option>
    <option value="normal text">normal text</option>
    <option value="long text option">long text option</option>
    <option value="very long text option">very long text option</option>
</select>
```

#### use `title` in your `option`

```css
select {
    width:75px; /*whatever you want*/
}
```

```html
<select name="college" id="college">
    <option value="1" title="small">1</option>
    <option value="2" title="normal text">2</option>
    <option value="3" title="long text option">3</option>
    <option value="4" title="very long text option">4</option>
</select>
```

#### use 3rd apps

You can choose a few that are available.. just going to give a couple of examples:

- [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)
- [jQtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

#### UPDATE:

**Notes:** The dropdown width can't be set. It's width depend on the `option`s values

Comment: The first two methods didnt work for me. Surely there's got to be a way apart from using plugins!

Comment: I forgot to mention that browsers won't let you format `option` tag. therefore those are the options you will find if you do a quick search online. If I really understood your question.

Comment: The dropdown-width itself cannot be set. It's width depend on the option-values. I added this to answer as a Note.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a late answer and possibly not 100% what you were looking for:
The dropdown width of my select-element covered nearly half the width of the screen.

It looks like the width of the dropped-down list is being controlled by the number of characters between

```
<option><?php SOME PHP-CODE  ?></option>
```

After I replaced:

```
    <div class='nobord' style='position: absolute; left: 60.2%; width: 15%; height: 11%; top:25%; background-color: transparent;'>
<?php $maxi=$results['numcountries']+1; 
      <select class='likeinput'  style='width: 100%' name='country' id='CountrySelector' >
<?php   for ($i = 0; $i<= $maxi; $i++) {
          if($results['Country'][$i]->countryname===$results['contact']->country){ ?>
            <option value='<?php echo $results['Country'][$i]->countryname ?>' selected='selected' ><?php echo $results['Country'][$i]->countryname; ?></option>
<?php     } else { ?>
            <option value='<?php echo $results['Country'][$i]->countryname ?>' ><?php echo $results['Country'][$i]->countryname ?></option>
<?php     } 
        } ?>       
      </select>
```

with:

```
      <div class='nobord' style='position: absolute; left: 60.2%; width: 15%; height: 11%; top:25%; background-color: transparent;'>
<?php   $maxi=$results['numcountries']+1; ?>
        <select class='likeinput'  style='width: 100%' name='country' id='CountrySelector' >
<?php     for ($i = 0; $i<= $maxi; $i++) {
            $val= $results['Country'][$i]->countryname;
            if($results['Country'][$i]->countryname===$results['contact']->country){ 
?>
              <option value='<?php echo $val?>' selected='selected' ><?php echo $val ?></option>
<?php       } else { ?>
              <option value='<?php echo $val?>' ><?php echo $val ?></option>
<?php       } 
          } ?>       
        </select>
```

the dropdown width corresponds to the width of the select-element.